# Do MovieClip's play() and stop() functions call add/remove ENTER_FRAME listener?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

Say we have a `MovieClip` called `mc` with two frames inside it.

1. If I call `mc.play();` - will that trigger somewhere inside the Flash System an `mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)` call?
2. If I call `mc.stop();` - will that remove that listener?
3. What happens if `mc` has only 1 frame? will Flash be smart enough to ignore it all?
4. Am I in any correct direction here??

Thank you

Eyal

Comment: You can check if it has the Event Listener with trace(mc.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)); after the play() and stop().

Answer (score 0):

1. **No**, you should manually call *addEventListener* as well as *removeEventListener*. There are no exclusions for all kind of objects.
2. ---
3. If `MovieClip` has only 1 frame it will looply (cyclic) play this frame *N* times per second.  `ENTER_FRAME` event will be dispatched *N* times per second also.

   *N* is your frame rate per second.
4. I hope now you are..